# Neo4j-import tool: Skip duplicate relationships

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-batch-inserter

Is it possible to skip importing duplicate relationships. Similar to 
`--skip-duplicate-nodes <true/false>` option. Something like `--skip-duplicate-relationships <true/false>`

I cant seem to find such an option in the latest documentation.

Cheers!

Comment: That you have to deal with the query. Using merge will be a good option but if your file is large then it can be the reason for the delay in insertion too.